# Data source is an invalid type in VB.net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I am querying the database to fill the Datagrid. I dont want everything in the database to be displayed on the table just some important information.

I am new to VB.net I am used to asp.net core MVC and entity frameworkork

> > Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
> > Here is my code below

```
    Private Sub GetTSANotification()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[notifyMe]"

        Dim DBConnection As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Notification").ConnectionString
        Using cmd As New SqlConnection(DBConnection)
            Using da As New SqlCommand(query)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    da.Connection = cmd
                    sda.SelectCommand = da
                    Using data As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(data)
                        notifyReport.DataSource = da
                        notifyReport.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
                End Using
            End Using
    End Sub
```

Here is my Datagrid.
I just want to display like 5 item from the DB, others in the DB column are not necessary for the user

```
    <asp:GridView CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" ID="notifyReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
                                    
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="id"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="customerName" HeaderText="Customer Name" SortExpression="customerName"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="customerEmail" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="customerEmail"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="fee" HeaderText="Fee" SortExpression="fee"></asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="feedType" HeaderText="Feed Type" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="feedType"></asp:BoundField>
                                         <asp:BoundField DataField="narrationDesc" HeaderText="Narration" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="narrationDesc"></asp:BoundField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Why not just query only the fields you required rather than Select * from NotifyMe.  Select Id, CustomerName.... From NotifyMe

Comment: That code should work. Try to clear the solution and rebuild everything. If the error persist use the debugger to check what happens in that code. Side note, your variable names are very confusing.

Comment: then select only part of the data `"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[notifyMe]"` --> `"SELECT *col1, col2, ... FROM [dbo].[notifyMe]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The beginning of wisdom is to call things their proper names"

So your code can be simplified and straightened out a bit:

```
Private Sub GetTSANotification()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[notifyMe]"

    Dim connStr As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Notification").ConnectionString

   
    Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(query, connStr)
      Dim data As New DataTable
      sda.Fill(data)
      notifyReport.DataSource = data
      notifyReport.DataBind()
    End Using
            
End Sub
```